# ADATA SX900 firmware downgrade failure

Tags: ssd, updates, firmware

I have an [ADATA SX900 SSD](http://www.adata.com/index.php?action=product_feature&cid=3&piid=169) with firmware 5.8.2. I am trying to downgrade firmware to 5.2.5, but my drive is refusing to accept firmware. It returns this error:

```
FATAL_ERROR: Firmware download failed with error:
(0x11000001:SF_SG_DEVICE_CHECK_CONDITION_ERROR).

ATA COMMAND: 0x0092 (146)
ATA FEATURE: 0x0003 (3)
Device Status: 0x0001 (1)
Driver Status: 0x0000 (0)
Host Status: 0x0008 (8 )
```

[image: Full error screenshot]

I need to downgrade because my SSD is corrupting my data and reseting all SMART values every 2 days.

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Is the drive directly connected to a SATA port or via an USB-to_SATA enclosure? Is the SATA port set to AHCI ?

Comment: Well I guess downgrading just isn’t possible. I suggest you contact ADATA about your issue and refrain from using the drive in the meantime.

Comment: It's connected directly. AHCI is set. Tried IDE mode too and a second computer. ADATA has no support at all :( I tried Patriot SandForce Updater under Windows and it showed that update was successful, but after reboot firmware remain the same.